# Cannot acces a page on my system,which is acessible everywhere in world

Tags: proxy, squid, cache

I need to open a website "http://www.book-pal.com/" , which is opening everywhere in world, but not with me. it shows a 404 page not found error and this is the content of the Cache, when i debugeed the http response:

```
Data Size   1206
Device  disk
Expires Thu Jan 01 1970 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (KART)
Fetch Count 8
Last Fetched    Thu Mar 22 2012 12:50:13 GMT+0500 (PKT)
Last Modified   Thu Mar 22 2012 12:50:13 GMT+0500 (PKT)
```

Can it be due to the fact that a cached page is being requested to me? in my path towards this site?
Some router in my way is caching this page?
FYI, i do not have a cache proxy server atleast on my gatway, not sure if it is present after it.

Is it possible that i can Force my browser to not to fect the cached copy?

Comment: If all you need to do is open the page and not actually solve the problem of *why* you can't open the page, pick an open proxy and use that or use `lynx` from one of your servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use Shift + F5 to force a refresh.

Also, make sure that the site is resolving to the same IP on your system as it is on others.

Comment: Already tried many times with Shit+F5 , on different browsers, not working. The site's IP is indeed resolvable.

Comment: Does it resolve to the same IP everywhere? 

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    book-pal.com
Address:  70.37.251.203
Aliases:  www.book-pal.com

Comment: Yes, its same everywhere

Comment: I guess you could try to use a public proxy server as @Ladadadada has mentioned. If that works then it could be your ISP?